# Is a high number of support vectors a sign of overfitting?

Tags: machine-learning, svm

I've tuned a SVM with radial kernel that has training error about 10%,
but test error is about 38%, which surprise me.

I tried to understand what may cause this and noticed the number of support vectors is high, about 50% of the observation are support vectors. Is this the cause of the problem? Does high number of support vectors leads to a high
variance SVM?

Here is the summary of the SVM.

```
Parameters:

   SVM-Type:  C-classification 

 SVM-Kernel:  radial 

       cost:  31.62 

      gamma:  1e-04 

Number of Support Vectors:  117

 ( 58 59 )

Number of Classes:  2 

Levels: 
 high low
```

Comment: Test error will always be larger than training error. Why are you surprised, precisely?

Comment: @user777 by the difference between training and test error, that is about 28%. I've applied the SVM to other dataset, the differences are usually about 5-10%.

Comment: But this is a different data set, correct? Perhaps the relationship between features and outcome is weaker in this data, or there are many low-quality input features, or you need a more specialized kernel function, or you need more data to learn the boundary in the feature space...

Comment: How many observations did you have in the training sample ?

Comment: @user777 that's true! I randomly split the observation set into training and test set with 50/50 split. I guess I didn't the expect the relationships between x and y are so different among them.

Comment: @fcoppens there are 196 in training set and 196 in test set, both are derived from random splitting the full dataset.

Comment: I think you have a problem of overfitting, there are some results on error bouds and the lnk with the number of support vectors but I am not an expert in that.  Nevertheless a very high fraction of support vectors is an indication of overfit.  Maybe you should re-phrase your question "Is a high number of support vectors a sign of overfitting ? "

Comment: @fcoppens I changed the title based on your suggestion. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

**YES**, a large number of support vectors is often a sign of overfitting.

The problem appears to be that you have chosen optimal hyperparameters based on training set performance, rather than independent test set performance (or, alternatively, cross-validated estimates).

### The problem

Never evaluate a set of hyperparameters based on training set performance, because you will inevitably end up with an immense overfit. Consider the RBF kernel:
$$K(\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v}) = \exp(-\gamma \|\mathbf{u}-\mathbf{v}\|^2).$$
Now, take the following limit case:
$$
\lim_{\gamma\rightarrow\infty} K(\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v}) = 
\left\{ \begin{matrix} 
0, & \text{if } \mathbf{u}\neq\mathbf{v},\\ 
1, & \text{otherwise.}
\end{matrix} \right.
$$
Which essentially means that, for $\gamma\rightarrow\infty$ the kernel matrix becomes the unit matrix. This allows the resulting model to **always** fit the training data perfectly, with each instance becoming a support vector, but learn absolutely nothing.

### The solution

If you want to optimize hyperparameters, you must always estimate the generalization performance of a given set of hyperparameters based on unseen data. The most common approach is via cross-validation, e.g. $k$-fold or leave-one-out.

Note that, when you are tuning hyperparameters based on cross-validation, it is still effectively possible to overfit. You can reduce this to some extent by using several iterations and/or more folds, but the inherent issue remains.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comments, I really like the example you give to demo the problem. I used the `turn` function in R to find the optimal parameter, and I believe it use 10-folder CV by default. The high test error rate is probably due to the splitting that gives different data characteristics between the two datasets because the sample size is small (about 400). Thanks for you answer to the question, I'd keep it in mind when apply SVM.